# emberjs get automatic controller

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to test my app with qunit and sinon. I want to test some behaviour of the controller including its setup on a transition. For example in '`setupController`' in a given route.

However the problem is that the controller is automatically created and I only know that you can get it with a '`controllerFor`' call in the route. How can I get at the auto generated controller(s) for a given page from the outside, e.g. `App.xxxxx`

Note that I tried doing a '`transitionTo`' passing the controller as the second argument but this means that '`setupController`' never gets called so I can't test the scenario I wanted to. If there were a way to force setupController to be called even when you pass the second argument this would do the job

Thanks for any help

Comment: Even though the controller is autogenerated you might still be able to get it by using `controlerFor`. Try it and let us know if that worked.

Comment: Also, once you get it working, would you be willing to share your basic setup for testing? We're working on an Ember app that we'd like to write tests for but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I tried doiing an Ember.controllerFor (where the specified controller was the one for the current route and view) but that didn't work for me. I don't know if there is another way, somehow getting the current route and then the controller from that. I had a look but could not see anything obvious

Comment: By the way for all the standard testing, ignoring the inability to get the current controller without polluting existing code, I am just using Qunit and sinonjs. I have a separate html file for testing which imports these (and Ember and my app of course) and then I have calls to Qunit'stest/asyncTest in other files. When I want to run the tests without a browser then I use phantomjs to run them. I used this page as a reference for running with phantomjs https://gist.github.com/gmarik/1305062

Comment: I should add that sinon lets you make a mock server and things like that to fake ajax requests. And you can obviously instantiate controllers and check their behaviour. My main stumbling blocks is checking transitions happen smoothly in various circumstances. e.g. a dynamic view from an existing context (e.g. from item in list  to edit item) vs from a url (to edit item) where the model must be fetched. I want to ensure all cases remain covered, as there can be a few permutations in terms of what data is ready when you arrive at a page